# Show "hit-enter message" with Syntax Highlighting?

Tags: global-command

To get a view of all function definitions in a file I type `:g/function/#`

Vim displays each line with the word "`function`" in a small "message window".  I'd like to have my defined syntax hightlighting applied to this output. Possible?

Comment: not possible unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlighting messages as output by `:print` and similar isn't possible.

But, you could

1. capture the output of the command (`:let output = execute('global/function/#')->split('\n')`)
2. display it in a popup window (or a regular new window) and add syntax highlighting

Alternately, `:vimgrep function %` (normally `/function/`, but since there are no pattern characters this is fine). Then use the quickfix features to navigate and have syntax highlighting directly in the actual buffer.